# Show CollectionView in CommunityToolkit.Maui Popup

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I'm trying to display a scrollable list in a popup with a CollectionView and I get an exception "**Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute**" as soon as it is displayed.
I don't understand why because my binded list with ItemsSource is never modified.

Thanks for your help.

This is PopupTest.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
           x:Class="Popup.PopupTest">

<Grid>
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Sources}"
                    ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                    SelectionMode="Single">

        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                               ItemSpacing="0" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="10,10,10,10"
                      RowSpacing="5">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Grid.Column="0"
                           Source="{Binding ...}"
                           WidthRequest="40"
                           HeightRequest="40"
                           Margin="15,10,25,10" />

                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{Binding ...}"
                           Margin="0,0,25,0"
                           FontSize="17"
                           LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                           MaxLines="2"
                           HorizontalOptions="Start"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />

                    <RadioButton Grid.Column="2"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding ...}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</Grid>
</toolkit:Popup>
```

This is PopupTest.xaml.cs

```
public partial class PopupTest : CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.Popup
{
    public ObservableCollection<...> Sources { get; set; }

    public PopupTest()
    {
        Sources = new ObservableCollection<...>([other list]);

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

This is how I display the popup

```
var popup = new PopupTest();
this.ShowPopup(popup);
```

Comment: If you remove the ItemSource, does the Popup load?

Comment: @FreakyAli Yes, if I replace the CollectionView with a Button or a TableView it works

Comment: Maybe you should try updating `Sources` after you have called `InitializeComponent` and see if that fixes your issue, it could be that your Collection is being updated and referenced at the same time which causes this

Comment: @FreakyAli I already tested this solution, and it doesn't work :(

Comment: May I ask 1. How you set the BindingContext for the ```PopupTest``` page? 2. For ```Sources = new ObservableCollection<...>([other list]);```, how you generate this ```other list```?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Thanks 1. I set it via ContentPage.BindingContext. I also tried without MVVM, binding with properties in the code behind, and I also got the exception. 2. The other list is immutable and retrieved from a static class.

Comment: What   .NET version and which platform do you use? I found a similar issue : [XamlC Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17563). And the workaround is to disable xaml compile

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT .net 8.0 and I get the exception on windows and android. I don't know if it's the same issue, on my side I have the exception at the line "this.ShowPopup(popup)"

Comment: Thanks for response. Right now, I've made a demo but not able to reproduce your issue. I think your project should be more complicated. So, if you just create a CollectionView on a ContentPage instead of using a Popup, will this error still happen? This may help us to identify if this issue is related to the CommunityToolkit Popup.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT yes, this issue is only related to the CommunityToolkit popup. I have no issu with the CollectionView in a ContentPage. I also tested adding a popup to the default MAUI project in net 8.0, and I also got the exception.

Comment: It's really weird. I also add an answer below with more details about how I create a demo based on your code. May I ask for your patience to check my answer if there is anything different with your demo or anything I haven't considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I made a demo using [CommunityToolkit Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup). I am using `.NET8.0` with `CommunityToolkit.Maui 7.0.1` targeting on Android emulator.

After I create a default maui project. I add a Popup Page to my project mostly based on your code. Here it is,

1.the XAML for Popup,

```
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.PopupTest"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             >
    <Grid WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="600">
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Sources}"
                    ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                    SelectionMode="Single">

            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                               ItemSpacing="0" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="10,10,10,10"
                      RowSpacing="5">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Grid.Column="0"
                           Source="{Binding ImageName}"
                           WidthRequest="40"
                           HeightRequest="40"
                           Margin="15,10,25,10" />

                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                           Margin="0,0,25,0"
                           FontSize="17"
                           LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                           MaxLines="2"
                           HorizontalOptions="Start"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />

                        <RadioButton Grid.Column="2"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
</toolkit:Popup>
```

2.the code behind for Popup.

```
public partial class PopupTest : Popup
{
    public PopupTest()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MyPopupViewModel();
    } 
}
```

3.the ViewModel for Popup. I just add some test data in it,

```
public class MyPopupViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Sources { get; set; }
    public IList<Item> items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();

    public MyPopupViewModel() 
    {
        items.Add(new Item { ImageName = "dotnet_bot.png", IsChecked = true, Name = "Item1" });
        items.Add(new Item { ImageName = "dotnet_bot.png", IsChecked = false, Name = "Item2" });
        items.Add(new Item { ImageName = "dotnet_bot.png", IsChecked = false, Name = "Item3" });
        items.Add(new Item { ImageName = "dotnet_bot.png", IsChecked = false, Name = "Item5" });
        items.Add(new Item { ImageName = "dotnet_bot.png", IsChecked = true, Name = "Item4" });
        Sources = new ObservableCollection<Item>(items);
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

And after I click the button on MainPage,

```
    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var popup = new PopupTest();
        this.ShowPopup(popup);
    }
```

Here is the effect on Android 13.0 - Pixel5 emulator,

[image]

Comment: I created a new .Net 8.0 project to test your code, and now I get the exception "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'handler.Container')" when I show the popup :-/ (on windows and android).

Here is my project, did I make a mistake please?  https://filetransfer.io/data-package/PnZ79WEt#link

Comment: Oh I see, in ```OnCounterClicked``` method, you should use ```var popup = new PopupPage();``` instead of ```var popup = new Popup();```.   ```PopupPage``` is the one you create in the project

Comment: No, I'm too ashamed  For the moment I have done otherwise for my needs, but I will still need a popup soon, I will test your solution at that time. Thanks !